# Como criar o meu próprio pacote/projeto para "composer" no github?

Tags: github, composer, packages

Eu nunca distribui uma biblioteca usando um repositório com [**composer**](https://getcomposer.org/), não tenho experiência com isto, o que tentei fazer é foi criar uma estrutura de pasta assim:

```
./
 |-- composer.json
 |-- src/
     |-- Test/
           |-- Foo.php
```

No arquivo `composer.json` do repositório eu adicionei o seguinte conteúdo:

```
{
    "name": "[vendor]/[nome do repositorio]",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Test": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Eu edito no meu projeto (na minha maquina o `composer.json`):

```
{
    "name": "foo/bar",
    "description": "Framwork foo",
    "type": "project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Foo bar",
            "email": "foo@bar.baz"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "[vendor]/[nome do repositorio]": "*"
    }
 }
```

Após isto eu executo o seguinte comando (linux):

```
$ cd /home/project1
$ php composer.phar update
```

Windows:

```
cd c:\wamp\www\project1
composer update
```

Mas ele retorna a seguinte falha:

> Problem 1
>      - The requested package brcontainer/composer-test could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Eu tentei trocar o `minimum-stability` para `dev`, mas houve o mesmo problema, faltou eu adicionar algo no repositório?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este erro ocorre devido a 3 possíveis fatores:

1. Erro de digitação
2. O pacote não esta disponível
3. Está tentando usar um pacote `dev`

O primeiro erro é fácil de entender, o problema é o segundo, não fica muito claro o que é "package" ou aonde devemos deixa-lo disponível, a principio achei que o composer consultava o github e/ou bitbucket, mas na verdade não é assim que funciona, você pode usar qualquer repositório, além do github, mas você terá que disponibilizar o `.git` como pacote e isto.

No próprio site do https://getcomposer.org se notar existe um link chamado [Browse Packages](https://packagist.org) é aqui que a mágica acontece:

<kbd>[image: Composer site links]</kbd>

Ao acessar somos levados ao https://packagist.org, em seguida basta você acessar com a sua conta clicando em use github (se for outro repositório como o bitbucket terá que criar uma conta manualmente, clique em *Create One Now* para isto):

<kbd>[image: Conta do Github]</kbd>

Após isto ele vai pedir as permissões necessárias é só aceitar, leia e depois aceite.

Depois no menu superior clique em [Submit](https://packagist.org/packages/submit), no campo "Repository URL (Git/Svn/Hg)", você deve colar o `.git` (suporta outros formatos) do githube, para pegar o .git vá até o seu repositório e na parte superior terá o link, por exemplo:

<kbd>[image: url do git]</kbd>

Após isto é só colar no campo da página [Submit](https://packagist.org/packages/submit) e em seguida clique em Check:

<kbd>[image: Enviar git]</kbd>

Se ocorrer o erro:

> The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.

É porque a página expirou, basta clicar no link [Submit](https://packagist.org/packages/submit) na parte superior e tentar novamente. Podem aparecer outros repositórios (de outras pessoas) com nomes semelhantes, é a oportunidade de pensar em um nome mais criativo para o seu, mas é totalmente opcional, basta clicar no botão Submit para confirmar.

Deve ficar algo semelhante a isto:

<kbd>[image: Package submited]</kbd>

É necessário criar um Release no github (se estiver usando github), para isto vá até Releases em seu repositório:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Em seguida clique no botão <kbd>Create a new release</kbd>, preencha o formulário e clique no botão <kbd>Publish release</kbd>

No entanto algum repositórios não possuem Releases (esse é o terceiro problema que citei no começo) mesmo estando no [Packagist](https://packagist.org/), isto porque o projeto esta em desenvolvimento ainda, então é necessário modificar o seu `composer.json` do seu projeto e adicionar isto:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
{
    "name": "foo/bar",
    "description": "Framwork foo",
    "type": "project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Foo bar",
            "email": "foo@bar.baz"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "[vendor]/[nome do repositorio]": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
 }
```

Após isto basta testar o seu repositório em seu projeto que esta na sua máquina:

```
cd c:\wamp\projeto1
composer update
```

O resultado tem que ser algo semelhante a isto:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing brcontainer/composer-test-2 (v1.0.0)
    Downloading: 100%
```

### Instalando por linha de comando ao seu projeto

Após prepara tudo ainda note que é possível baixar o pacote sem adicionar ao seu `composer.json` do projeto, assim:

```
composer require [vendor]/[nome do repositorio]
```

Ou:

```
php composer.phar require [vendor]/[nome do repositorio]
```

No entanto se o projeto não tiver um Release é necessário executar o comando assim:

```
composer require [vendor]/[nome do repositorio]:dev-master
```

Ou:

```
php composer.phar require [vendor]/[nome do repositorio]:dev-master
```

Answer (score 2):

Quando você coloca seu pacote como dependência do projeto, precisa especificar se quer alguma *constraint* de versão. Se você ainda não versionou essa dependência, precisa configurar para usar um branch dele como dependência.

Usando uma constraint de versão:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "[vendor]/[nome do repositorio]": "^1.0"
}
```

Usando um branch:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "[vendor]/[nome do repositorio]": "dev-master"
}
```

Comment: Obrigado vou tentar :)