# NPM, Bower e Composer, qual usar?

Tags: composer, npm, bower

Alguém pode me explicar a diferença entre NPM, Bower e Composer.

Eles são todos gerenciadores de pacotes, correto?

Mas quando cada um deve ser usado?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sim correto, são todos gerenciadores de pacotes. Mas, o tipo de pacotes que gerem é diferente.

Posso começar já por explicar que o composer é um gerenciador de pacotes focado em php (há exceções, por ex também dá para "instalar" jQuery mas por convenção e por hábito as pessoas tendem para escolher bower para este efeito específico), se interiorizar que composer é para php (apesar de haver exceções) não irás fazer confusão. Enquanto os outros não são para pacotes php.

Quanto aos outros podem ser confundidos, sim, mas vou tentar fazer com que deixem de ser.

Npm é maioritariamente para gerir pacotes/modulos de node.js, tem algumas exceções mas normalmente estas têm a possibilidade de escolher qual usar, ex: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html .

Bower serve para gerir pacotes de front-end, como html, css (ex, bootstrap etc..), javascript (ex. Jquery etc..), tudo o que tiver a ver com layout (código somente interpretado pelo browser, navegador, não pelo servidor), muitas vezes até templates inteiros podem ser descarregados com o bower, ex https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE.

Comment: Está excelente +1

Answer (score 10):

- `composer` é para pacotes PHP (apesar de ser possível instalar mais do que PHP, podendo até instalar coisas como bootstrap e jQuery) e ele instala pacotes disponíveis no https://packagist.org

  > Como criar e publicar um pacote https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102747/3635
- `npm` para `node.js` e instala pacotes disponíveis no https://npmjs.com/

  > Como criar e publicar um pacote https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages
- o `bower` serve principalmente para pacotes front-end, mas há exceções

  > Como criar e publicar um pacote https://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/

Answer (score 9):

`NPM` é para projetos em nodejs, se você estiver desenvolvendo algum projeto com NodeJS a melhor opção é esta.

`Bower` é para dependências de projetos web, focado para front-end, como jQuery (o Bower precisa de nodejs pra executar)

e o `Composer` é um gerenciador de dependências focado no PHP.

Há um outro link no stackoverflow em inglês, onde alguém explica melhor um pouco a diferença, segue o link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918517/npm-bower-composer-differences

Comment: Com o Composer também é possível instalar dependências, como jQuery. Ele é focado em PHP, mas dá pra usar com outras coisas .

Comment: @WallaceMaxters como citei na minha resposta ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, de facto é verdade tinha mesmo a certeza que era só php, pelos vistos estava errado :/... Erro meu, e a minha foi a aceite e não merecia

Comment: @Miguel não a problema Miguel, todas respostas foram uteis, você pode editar a sua e adicionar o detalhe sem problema, desde que ajude a comunidade não vejo problema algum ;)

Comment: Obagdo por me deixares corrigir a resposta @GuilhermeNascimento, com informação provida por ti

Answer (score 5):

**npm** é o gerenciador de pacotes do nodejs. Usado em projetos javascript e cuida das dependências de módulos javascript do seu projeto. Veja mais em [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/)

**composer** é o gerenciador de pacotes backend, mais usado em PHP, porém existem outros projetos e CMS como o drupal que o composer cuida de toda a dependência de módulos do projeto. Veja mais em [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

**bower** é um gerenciador de componentes front-end, é necessário colocar ele com o npm. Gerencia as dependências de front-end do seu projeto. Veja mais em bower.io.