# Criar um evento / plugin para Composer

Tags: php, composer

Desenvolvi um WebServer Portable e também estou criando um console portable para usar o Composer.

Estou com um problema. Eu preciso criar um plugin para o Composer.

Eu preciso que ao fazer o download de qualquer pacote com o Composer, ele edite os "scripts" do compositor.json desse pacote, para que ele funcione no console portable.

Ao fazer o download do Laravel, por exemplo:

composer.json original:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

composer.json editado pelo plugin:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "F:/portable_php_path/php.exe -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

- Observe que um caminho físico foi gerado para o php.exe, porque na versão portable, ele poderá estar em qualquer caminho.

(A minha dúvida é quanto a criação do plugin para Composer. Não tenho problemas para editar o compositor.json com PHP)

Eu li o tutorial para criar um plugin no site do Composer, mas fiquei confuso. (https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md)

Se tiver outra maneira de fazer isso, também é interessante. Aceito outras sugestões e ideias.

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Quando roda o composer via linha de comando o PHP já esta provavelmente na **variável `PATH` do sistema operacional**, então não é necessário passar o caminho completo do PHP:

```
"F:/portable_php_path/php.exe -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
```

Basta chamar assim:

```
 "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
```

Isso pois o composer é escrito em PHP e depende dele, então na interface CLI sempre estará disponivel quando usar o composer

Para criar PACOTES para composer veja esta resposta:

- [Como criar o meu próprio package para composer no github?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100158/3635)

É claro que dá para usar outros tipos de repositórios, como Bitbucket e até repositórios próprios, mas se for algo assim especifique que ficará mais fácil explicar na resposta.

### PSR-0, PSR-4 e autoload

Recomendo que antes de aprender como criar um pacote para composer aprender sobre PSR-4 e PSR-0 (este esta em desuso, mas ainda existem pacotes que o usam):

- PSR-0: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/
- PSR-4: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/
- [O que é spl_autoloader_register em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88039/3635)
- [PSR-4 em um projeto MVC ou não?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80060/3635)
- [Quais são as diferenças entre __autoload e spl_autoload_register?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75105/3635)
- [O que significa PSR?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32295/3635)
- [Classe autoload PSR4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91512/3635)

Comment: Eu criei um server portátil (portable), que poderá ser executado até de um Pendrive. Agora estou desenvolvendo um console portable também. Então, nada existirá nas variáveis de ambiente. Preciso mesmo usar um caminho fisico para o PHP, seja substituindo de alguma forma no composer.json automaticamente quando algum (todos) pacotes forem instalados, ou de outra forma

Comment: Mas para rodar o composer no proprio CLI será necessário executar `set PATH=...` na interface CLI, o que equivale a "existir" @Gilsones

Comment: Eu já desenvolvi o Console portable, e funciona perfeitamente, sem variável de ambiente. O problema mesmo acontece quando um composer.json tem um "script" que chame o php

Comment: E como executa o composer?

Comment: Assim: https://jsfiddle.net/gv74vLf4/

Comment: Não perguntei do script, perguntei de como executa os comandos. Então como você chamada o composer no terminal?

Comment: Não, é por um formulário HTML, via post, por enquanto... se der tudo certo, crio algo mais cômodo.

Comment: Então você não quer criar um "plugin" composer, o que você quer é criar algo proprio totalmente voltado para um necessidade sua especifica.

Comment: A necessidade é adicionar um função ao Composer, assim que baixar algum pacote, verificar seu composer.json e fazer a substituição. Realmente estou confuso se é possível fazer através de um plugin, ou se pelo código do JSFiddle que postei acima, seria possível adicionar eventos. Não quero mexer no código do Composer, pois pretendo disponibilizar esse server portable

Comment: @Gilsones então composer parece ser meio desnecessário, só para o autoload faz a necessidade, ou talvez nada seja necessário, instale tudo o que tem que instalar no pen-drive e disponibilize assim.